# Android Button setText not being updated

Tags: android, android-button

I am writing code for an inbox-like activity which has a button that leads to the messages. This button has a text field that counts how many messages are in the inbox.

My problem is that the button's text field is not changing when the number of messages changes. It is not a problem of the app not checking for updates, and the code with setText is being called with the correct number to update.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v("onCreate", "Main");
    // Checking if there is login
    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        navigateToLogin();
    } else {

    // Setting pointers for buttons.
    // onClick methods follow.
    askButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAsk);
    ansButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAnswer);
    inboxButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCenter);

    mUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    updateInbox();

}
```

This is the method that checks for new messages and updates the button.

```
    private void updateInbox() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Updating inbox");

    ParseQuery responses = new ParseQuery(ParseConstants.CLASS_ANSWER);
    responses.whereMatches(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, mUser.getObjectId());

    try {
        responsesCount = responses.count();
        Log.v("responses count" ,""+responsesCount);
        if (responsesCount > 0) {
            inboxButton.setText(String.valueOf(responsesCount));
        }
        Log.v("InboxActivity","Label set to " + responsesCount);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.v("InboxActivity", e.getMessage());
    }           
}
```

updateInbox gets called correctly and in the correct moments, so I only added its code to make this as clean as possible. Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:clickable="false"
>

<Button
    android:layout_width="80sp"
    android:layout_height="80sp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCenter"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/black_overlay"
    android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"/>
```

EDIT:

Hi all, thanks for the help. I figured out the problem and posted it as an answer. It was a logical error, nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
inboxButton.post(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
          inboxButton.setText(String.valueOf(responsesCount));
      }
});
```

(responsesCount should be final)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

if (responsesCount > 0) {
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.my_layout); //where my_layout is the layout file where the button resides.
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button, "Set button text here");// where button is id of the button.
}
```

findViewById doesn't exist for a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for you

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                     public void run() {
                       if (responsesCount > 0) {
                          inboxButton.setText(String.valueOf(responsesCount));
                                    }
             }
         });
```

**You may use AsyncTask for smoothness of app flow.**

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the text was only getting updated when the number of responses was > 0. The button was updating correctly otherwise so I had to put an else statement to make sure the button always got updated. I edited the question with the correct answer in comments.

```
    responsesCount = responses.count();
    Log.v("responses count" ,""+responsesCount);
    if (responsesCount > 0) {
        inboxButton.setText(String.valueOf(responsesCount));

    ///////////////////////////////////
    // MY EDIT HERE
    //} else{
    //  inboxButton.setText("");
    ///////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate and force-reload layout of your Button:

```java
if (responsesCount > 0) {
    inboxButton.setText(String.valueOf(responsesCount));
    inboxButton.invalidate();
    inboxButton.forceLayout();
}
```